# Fire events after setting element.value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fill in a form in javascript , and also to simulate it as I have typed it by firing all kind of events.

Here's what I have done so far :

```
domElement.value = "123123";
fireKeyEvent(domElement);


function fireKeyEvent(ele) {
    fireSpecificKeyEvent(ele,"keyup");
    fireSpecificKeyEvent(ele,"keydown");
    fireSpecificKeyEvent(ele,"keypress");
}

function fireSpecificKeyEvent(ele, eventName) {
    try {
          var evObj = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
          evObj.initUIEvent( eventName, true, true, window, 1 );
          console.log("eleid:"+ele.getAttribute("id"));
          console.log("eleValue:"+ele.getAttribute("value"));
          ele.dispatchEvent(evObj);
          //evObj.keyCode = 93;
          ele.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        }catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
}
```

It works fine most of the times, but sometimes it fails on some input text boxes. Are `keyup , keydown , keydown` enough to simulate all kinds of events.

`createEvent('UIEvents')` is this the correct implementation, or should i use keyEvent or KeyBoardEvent.

I am using chrome BTW. Can anybody show me an example of keyEvent or KeyBoardEvent, after I have already set the value using `element.value`

EDIT:

These events don't seem to fill in the form and submit at this link :

[link](https://wellsfargo.customercarenet.com/ccn/wellsfargo/mymortgage.html#pid=HOME-C)

What is missing.

Comment: No, `keyup` and `keydown` is not enough to trigger all kinds of events, it triggers just those events, specifically, no other events, like `paste`, `input`, `change`, `click` or any other event that could potentially have an event handler.

Comment: so I can add change, input and click in fireKeyevent method() or do they are handled differently.

Comment: What is your exact goal here?

Comment: no particular goal here, i just want to handle all kinds of form inputs . Which may occur sometimes. I even set the input.value, but they are not really set because events attached to it not fire.

Comment: [link](https://wellsfargo.customercarenet.com/ccn/wellsfargo/mymortgage.html#pid=HOME-C) try filling in this web site the form and press login . It wont detect anything you entered

Comment: edited the question and added a link